# Encrypt logcat output in kernel side

Tags: android, logging, encryption, linux-kernel, xor

I try add simple encryption to log file created by logcat in Android. For the performance, I add encryption in read function instead of write (driver/staging/android/logger.c)

```
    /*
     * do_read_log_to_user - reads exactly 'count' bytes from 'log' into the
     * user-space buffer 'buf'. Returns 'count' on success.
     *
     * Caller must hold log->mutex.
     */
    static ssize_t do_read_log_to_user(struct logger_log *log,
                       struct logger_reader *reader,
                       char __user *buf,
                       size_t count)
    {
        size_t len;
    unsigned int i;
    size_t _size;
    unsigned char *str;

    /*
     * We read from the log in two disjoint operations. First, we read from
     * the current read head offset up to 'count' bytes or to the end of
     * the log, whichever comes first.
     */
    len = min(count, log->size - reader->r_off);

    // added
    _size= strlen(log->buffer);
    printk(KERN_INFO "_size=%d, len=%d, count=%d, logsize=%d, r_off=%d\n", _size, len, count, log->size, reader->r_off);
    str = kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);
    if(str==NULL)
        printk(KERN_ERR "logger: failed to allocate buffer\n");
    memcpy(str,log->buffer,len);
    for(i=0;i < _size; i++)
        str[i] ^=14; //XOR encryption here
//  if (copy_to_user(buf, log->buffer + reader->r_off, len))
    if (copy_to_user(buf, str + reader->r_off, len))    //changed here
        return -EFAULT;

    /*
     * Second, we read any remaining bytes, starting back at the head of
     * the log.
     */
    if (count != len) {
//      if (copy_to_user(buf + len, log->buffer, count - len))
        if (copy_to_user(buf + len, str, count - len))  //changed here
            return -EFAULT;
    }

    reader->r_off = logger_offset(reader->r_off + count);

    if(str!=NULL) {
        kfree(str);
        str=NULL;   
    }

    return count;
}
```

but it seems that it does not work as expected. When I run adb logcat, the error message is displayed from this segment code (/system/core/logcat/logcat.cpp)

```
            else if (entry->entry.len != ret - sizeof(struct logger_entry)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read: unexpected length. Expected %d, got %d\n",
                        entry->entry.len, ret - sizeof(struct logger_entry));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
```

Did I miss something here ?

## Updated:

I modified the code just to store data to temp `str` then perform XOR on it before copying it to user.

```
    /* Allocate the memory for storing plain text */
    str = kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);
    if(str == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "logger: failed to allocate buffer\n");
        return -ENOMEM; 
    }
    memcpy(str, log->buffer + reader->r_off, len);
    /* Start: Add a simple XOR encryption here */
    for(i=0;i < strlen(str); i++)
        str[i] ^= 14;
    /* End: Add a simple XOR encryption here */

//  if (copy_to_user(buf, log->buffer + reader->r_off, len))    //Original code
    if (copy_to_user(buf, str, len))                //Modified code
        return -EFAULT;
```

However, it seems that same error still displayed and I'm sure that the problem is from the following code

```
// Start: Add a simple XOR encryption here
for(i=0;i < strlen(str); i++)
    str[i] ^= 14;
// End: Add a simple XOR encryption here
```

because if I remove it, it works as original code. And I dont find anything wrong here ? Anyone see something weird here ???

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should show a unified diff to the original sources. Someone familiar with kernel development and the sources will be used to reading diffs.

I can see a few issues with the code

- When the `kmalloc()` fails, you print an error message, but copy to `str` anyway. A sure recipe for disaster.
- `_size= strlen(log->buffer)` I don't know, if the buffer is NUL terminated, especially, since there seems to be a `log->size` member. If it is not NUL terminated, the `strlen()` will either report a size too large or run until it hits a non-accessible page, which might result in an access error.
- You allocate a buffer of `min(...)` size, but copy `_size` bytes into it. When there's a mismatch between the two, you will corrupt the heap memory.
- You use `strlen()` to detect the needed buffer size, but do a `memcpy()` afterwards. *Usually*, you shouldn't mix `str*()` and `mem*()` functions, stay with either one or the other.

Comment: Thank for your comments, Olaf. Because this is just a draft so I didn't check the return of `kmalloc()` and `_size= strlen(log->buffer)`. Android log used ring buffer for storing and transferring  the data but it's sad to say that I did not get it clearly :(. Another point is that `copy_to_user()` function only deals with single quantum at a time so variable `len` I used in `memcpy(str,log->buffer,len);` do the wrong thing